# Downloading layout.xml for Android app and using

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic, runtime

The scenario is as follows. My App is basically a remote for home automation. It controls external devices like a heater, air conditioning, windows aso. Since every device has a different set of possible actions with a variety of in and output parameters I would like to use a custom layout for every device. The idea now is, that a devices manufacturer would just provide the layout.xml and maybe custom button styles (as .png or whatever) etc. The main reason to do this and instead of simply providing every interface-layout out of the box, is that there are going to be many thousands of those. So the interfaces would be downloadable content then.

Given that the layout.xml is already downloaded and saved somewhere on the phone, how can I now make use of it and tell my app to use that new layout when creating the Activity?

I already played a little bit with [this example](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+blogspot/hsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29), but it didn't really help me that much.

Your help is very much appreciated.

(Yes I did read the developer guidelines and concerns about downloading code/content at runtime)

Comment: you cant use downloaded layouts, sorry

Comment: If anyone is interested in trying this: there is an open source app AnDroidDraw that has a simple class for starting with.   reference: https://code.google.com/p/droiddraw/source/browse/trunk/AnDroidDraw/src/org/droiddraw/android/ViewInflater.java - I can post a slightly improved one that parses some colors, ImageView placeholders. I'd like to see if someone wants to expand on this.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're able to load external code using the link you provided, you would still have to compile the XMLs that you're planning to load. Android does not load the xml file when creating a view it gets compiled at build time. It's also used to generate access constants stored on `R` class, which will be a problem as well.

The preferred way of achieving your task would be to have your own XML format (or any other if you like) and load the layout based on this custom format. Of course this will be much more work.